# What does the GridView.DataBind method do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

What does the `Gridview.DataBind` method do, and when should it be used? I am running an update procedure on my `GridView`, which works fine. However, after the update completes, the changes are not not shown until after I log out and back into my website.

Is `DataBind` the correct method to see the changes immediately?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? I think this way it is better described. See @JohnSaunders link above.

Comment: What "updates" are being performed?  Getting the data into the grid, changing things in code, changing things within the grid...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to apply a DataSource to a GridView in code, then I'd have to bind it to the GridView Control before it could use it:

```
theGridView.DataSource = SomeClassWithData.toArray
theGridView.DataBind()
```

If I am correct at interpreting your rather limited description, then I would say you have a GridView in which you pull data into your application in memory...then you run some kind of update on the data, but never update the in-memory object...

Be more specific with how you're populating your GridView's DataSource if you want a more specific reply.

Comment: Yes I guess it's the in memory part that I don't have applied. Persisting it in Memory. I am using a Table Adapter to bring in a stored proc "Update". I am using a method written in my Class to Update the grid on a button click event. Here is the code for my Method.: `code    public void ReassignIndividual(int oIndividualID, int oNewParentID)
    {
        individualTableAdapter ind = new individualTableAdapter();
        ind.reassign_Individual(oIndividualID, oNewParentID);
    }code`